# aggregate df rows into one column while preserving the unique attribute for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following df (filtered version for a single Job #)

| index | Job # | Name | Timesheet Activity | Customer ID | Invoice Date | Completion Date | Invoice # | Status | Job Type | Jobs Total Revenue | Jobs Total Costs | Jobs Gross Margin | Jobs Gross Margin % | Assigned Technicians | Primary Technician | Business Unit | Prevailing Wage | Booked By | Job Number | Timesheet Activity Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5123 | 56618.0 | Carlos Meza | Driving | 5779854.0 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 56618.0 | Completed | Overhead Door (Sold) Job Walk | 18828.33 | 14484.21 | 4344.12 | 0.23072253354386715 | Donald Pearson, Carlos Meza , Joshua Williams | Carlos Meza | DOOR COMM | 1.0 | Mike Bailie | 56618.0 | 2023-10-24 00:00:00, 2023-10-25 00:00:00 |
| 5124 | 56618.0 | Carlos Meza | Working | 5779854.0 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 56618.0 | Completed | Overhead Door (Sold) Job Walk | 18828.33 | 14484.21 | 4344.12 | 0.23072253354386715 | Donald Pearson, Carlos Meza , Joshua Williams | Carlos Meza | DOOR COMM | 1.0 | Mike Bailie | 56618.0 | 2023-10-24 00:00:00, 2023-10-25 00:00:00 |
| 5125 | 56618.0 | Donald Pearson | Driving | 5779854.0 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 56618.0 | Completed | Overhead Door (Sold) Job Walk | 18828.33 | 14484.21 | 4344.12 | 0.23072253354386715 | Donald Pearson, Carlos Meza , Joshua Williams | Carlos Meza | DOOR COMM | 1.0 | Mike Bailie | 56618.0 | 2023-10-24 00:00:00, 2023-10-26 00:00:00 |
| 5126 | 56618.0 | Donald Pearson | Working | 5779854.0 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 56618.0 | Completed | Overhead Door (Sold) Job Walk | 18828.33 | 14484.21 | 4344.12 | 0.23072253354386715 | Donald Pearson, Carlos Meza , Joshua Williams | Carlos Meza | DOOR COMM | 1.0 | Mike Bailie | 56618.0 | 2023-10-24 00:00:00, 2023-10-25 00:00:00, 2023-10-26 00:00:00 |
| 5127 | 56618.0 | Joshua Williams | Driving | 5779854.0 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 56618.0 | Completed | Overhead Door (Sold) Job Walk | 18828.33 | 14484.21 | 4344.12 | 0.23072253354386715 | Donald Pearson, Carlos Meza , Joshua Williams | Carlos Meza | DOOR COMM | 1.0 | Mike Bailie | 56618.0 | 2023-10-24 00:00:00, 2023-10-26 00:00:00 |
| 5128 | 56618.0 | Joshua Williams | Working | 5779854.0 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 56618.0 | Completed | Overhead Door (Sold) Job Walk | 18828.33 | 14484.21 | 4344.12 | 0.23072253354386715 | Donald Pearson, Carlos Meza , Joshua Williams | Carlos Meza | DOOR COMM | 1.0 | Mike Bailie | 56618.0 | 2023-10-24 00:00:00, 2023-10-26 00:00:00 |
| 5129 | 56618.0 | Kelvin Taylor | Driving | 5779854.0 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 56618.0 | Completed | Overhead Door (Sold) Job Walk | 18828.33 | 14484.21 | 4344.12 | 0.23072253354386715 | Donald Pearson, Carlos Meza , Joshua Williams | Carlos Meza | DOOR COMM | 1.0 | Mike Bailie | 56618.0 | 2023-07-11 00:00:00 |
| 5130 | 56618.0 | Kelvin Taylor | Working | 5779854.0 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 56618.0 | Completed | Overhead Door (Sold) Job Walk | 18828.33 | 14484.21 | 4344.12 | 0.23072253354386715 | Donald Pearson, Carlos Meza , Joshua Williams | Carlos Meza | DOOR COMM | 1.0 | Mike Bailie | 56618.0 | 2023-07-11 00:00:00 |

Now what i want is that for single job # there should be only one row and every technician detail of activity and activity time to be preserved,

I have tried to achieve this by aggregating the df , But the problem is in doing so I am losing the unique identification for each Name and Technician Activity.

What I am expecting is:

| index | Customer ID | Invoice Date | Completion Date | Job # | Invoice # | Assigned Technicians | Primary Technician | Total Technician Paid Time | Business Unit | Prevailing Wage | Booked By | Job Number | Technician #1 | Driving Activity Date(s) #1 | Timesheet Activity #1 | Total Driving Duration (Decimal) #1 | Working Activity Date(s) #1 | Activity #1 | Total Working Time Duration #1 | Technician #2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5779854.0 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 2023-10-26 00:00:00 | 56618.0 | 56618.0 | Donald Pearson, Carlos Meza , Joshua Williams | Carlos Meza | 50.88333333 | DOOR COMM | 1.0 | Mike Bailie | 56618.0 | Carlos Meza | 2023-10-24, 2023-10-25 | Driving | 0.9 | 2023-10-24, 2023-10-24, 2023-10-25 | Working | 14.33333333 | Donald Pearson |

Comment: I think it is right to [make sample minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and ask about the logic.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to apply a custom aggregate function after grouping by "Job #", this custom aggregate function will perform the required transformation on each group.

```
def custom_aggregate(group):
    # Assuming you want to concatenate unique activities for each name
    names = group['Name'].unique()
    c = 1
    for n in names:
        group[f"technician {c}"] = n
        for ac, sub_group in group[group["Name"] == n].groupby("Timesheet Activity"):
            group[f'technician {c} {ac} Activity'] = ac
            group[f'technician {c} {ac} Activity Duration'] = sub_group["Duration (Decimal)"].values[0]
            group[f'technician {c} {ac} Activity Dates'] = sub_group["Timesheet Activity Date"].values[0]
        c += 1
    return group

result_df = aggregated_df.groupby('Job #').apply(custom_aggregate)
```

The loop in the custom aggregate function  will go over each name for that Job # and will make new column for each technician name then again subgrouping on Timesheet Activity and making column for respective Activity.